# Swap the first and third word in a sentence (sed)

Tags: shell, sed

I want to swap the first and third word in a sentence using sed.

My code looks something like this:

```
sed 's/\^ \([a-zA-Z]\*\) \(\^[a-zA-Z]\)  \([a-zA-Z]\*\) \(\^[a-zA-Z]\) \([a-zA-Z]\*\) \(.\*\) / \5 \2 \3 \4 \1 \6 /g' $1
```

A word contains only lower and uppercase characters. A character which is not a-z A-Z is a separator. My code does nothing :)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] and clarify why you have to use sed as opposed awk or some other tool.

Answer (score 0):

Do not escape the `*` character:

```
sed 's/^\([a-zA-Z]*\)\([^a-zA-Z]\)\([a-zA-Z]*\)\([^a-zA-Z]\)\([a-zA-Z]*\)\(.*\) /\5\2\3\4\1\6/g' $1
```

Also, you don't need the spaces between the regrouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "wordone wordtwo wordthree wordfour wordfive" \
| sed -Ee 's/^([[:alpha:]]+) ([[:alpha:]]+) ([[:alpha:]]+)/\3 \2 \1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([a-zA-Z]*)([^a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+[^a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z]*)(.*)/\3\2\1\4/' infile
```

### Example #1

```
$ line="one two three four five"
$ echo "$line" | sed -r 's/^([a-zA-Z]*)([^a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+[^a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z]*)(.*)/\3\2\1\4/'
```

**Output:**

```
three two one four five
```

### Example #2

```
$ line="one,two,three,four,five"
$ echo "$line" | sed -r 's/^([a-zA-Z]*)([^a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z]+[^a-zA-Z]+)([a-zA-Z]*)(.*)/\3\2\1\4/'
```

**Output:**

```
three,two,one,four,five
```

Comment: Second example should be `echo "$line"` instead of `echo "line"`.